# Display 2nd child table value when use left join and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables Category, Product and Sku and they have parent child relationship.

I want first product records where product id's all sku must match from sku table and same for category when category id's all product must match in product table.

Now the problem here I want to display sku id here along with category id. Is it possible to do it??

Here is the query :

```
SELECT cat.category_id FROM Category cat
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT product.product_id
  FROM Product product
  LEFT JOIN Sku sku ON product.sku_id = sku.sku_details_id
  GROUP BY product.product_id
  HAVING COUNT(product.product_id) = COUNT(sku.sku_details_id)
  ) childProduct ON cat.product_id = childProduct.product_id
  GROUP BY cat.category_id
  HAVING COUNT(cat.category_id) = COUNT(childProduct.product_id)
```

**Sample data**

```
Category 

cat1 prd1 prd2
cat2 prd3

Product
prd1 sku1 sku2 sku3 sku4 : cat1
prd2 sku1 sku2 sku3 sku4 : cat1
prd3 sku1 sku4 : cat2

Sku
sku1 
sku2
sku3
sku4
```

**Result should be**

```
cat1,sku1,sku2,sku3,sku4
```

Comment: please post some records from tables also

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE Category (category_id VARCHAR(10),Product_Id VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO Category VALUES('cat1','prd1');
INSERT INTO Category VALUES('cat1','prd2');
INSERT INTO Category VALUES('cat2','prd3');

CREATE TABLE Product (Product_Id VARCHAR(10),sku_id VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd1','sku1');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd1','sku2');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd1','sku3');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd1','sku4');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd2','sku1');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd2','sku2');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd2','sku3');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd2','sku4');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd3','sku1');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES('prd3','sku4');

CREATE TABLE Sku (sku_details_id VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO Sku VALUES('sku1'); 
INSERT INTO Sku VALUES('sku2');
INSERT INTO Sku VALUES('sku3');
INSERT INTO Sku VALUES('sku4');
```

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT cat.category_id,P.sku_id
FROM Category cat
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT product.product_id
  FROM Product product
  INNER JOIN Sku sku ON product.sku_id = sku.sku_details_id
  GROUP BY product.product_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product.sku_id) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sku_details_id) FROM Sku)
  ) childProduct ON cat.product_id = childProduct.product_id
  JOIN Product P ON P.product_id = cat.product_id
  GROUP BY cat.category_id,P.sku_id
```

**Output:**

```
| CATEGORY_ID | SKU_ID |
|-------------|--------|
|        cat1 |   sku1 |
|        cat1 |   sku4 |
|        cat1 |   sku3 |
|        cat1 |   sku2 |
```

Comment: @HiteshRakhadia, You are welcome. If you found this answer is useful and fix your problem then accept this as answer. This will help someone.

Comment: Hi I am getting sku id but I am also getting unnecessary category id. Because if I am adding another group by value so getting result is change

Comment: @HiteshRakhadia, Check the updated answer. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: @HiteshRakhadia, Are you check it. Is it helpful or not?